# Big O and Theta for loop

Tags: c++, for-loop, time-complexity, big-o

```
for(int i = 2; i < n*n; i = i*i)
    for(int j = 1; j < i; j++)
```

im really confused on how the `n*n` and `i*i` affect each other
my assumption is that it is O(n^2loglogn)
but i dont really know how to derive it

Comment: Since both O() and Theta() are sets of functions, and O() is the set of functions for which there exists a constant such that for sufficiently big input all executions take longer (this is a simplification), you can just use an intuitively large function for O(n). Theta(), on the other hand, requires that the function is also a lower bound, so that's harder.
O(nˆ3) seems easy to prove. I can't help with Theta(), as my brain is too feeble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm leaning a little bit out of my base knowledge, so take the following with a grain of salt.

For the raw topic:

Your iterator forms the series 2, 2<sup>2</sup>, 2<sup>2</sup><sup><sup>2</sup></sup>, 2<sup>2</sup><sup><sup>2</sup></sup><sup><sup><sup>2</sup></sup></sup>...
This is known as [Tetration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration).
Tetration has two inverse functions, which are the super-root and the [super-logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super-logarithm). The latter is relevant here, as we have slog<sub>2</sub>(n<sup>2</sup>) iterations of the outer loop.

But I think using this is not required. What we do in the end is to sum up the steps of the inner loops, and all of those save the last one summed up are together less that the last one, as tetrations grow with an extreme speed (it would already hold if we'd only double the value). This gives us a factor of 2, which we can ignore in Landau notation.
Important is thus only the last inner loop, which is bound by n<sup>2</sup>. This is an upper bound (less than 2n<sup>2</sup> inner steps in total) and also a lower bound assuming that n<sup>2</sup> is actually hit. Thus my answer would be Θ(n<sup>2</sup>), but I'm not sure if I didn't made a mistake in my thought process.
Would be nice to have another opinion, like somebody commenting if he thinks I'm right or wrong here.

Edit: based on the comment by SomeWittyUsername, here is a rough draft for the proof:

Let us denote the series that the iterator `i` undergoes by `f(t), t = 1..t_max`

First of all, we have that `f(t) >= 2` for every step, as it is initialized that way and only increases.

[image]

The inner loop has f(t) iterations for the t-th iteration of the outer loop. Thus the total steps are `sum (t = 1..t_max) f(t) <= 2 * f(t_max)`.
`f(t_max) <= n*n`
`->`
total steps are less than 2n<sup>2</sup> which is element of Θ(n<sup>2</sup>)

Comment: Looks good, but I think the statement *"all of those save the last one summed up are together less that the last one"* needs to be proved.

Comment: @SomeWittyUsername Added a rough draft for a proof.

Comment: Looks good. I took the liberty to rewrite the calculations in latex, since it was very hard to read. Hope it's ok